# Importing Facebook contacts on my website through yahoo contact importer

Tags: php, facebook, yahoo

I'm developing a php web-site which should give the possibility to invite Facebook friends of the user.

I've tried [openinviter](http://openinviter.com/index.php) but doesn't work, after googling I think the problem is Facebook does not allow friends'email retrieving through API, nor sending them messages (am I right?)
But there is an authorized application, Yahoo! contact importer, which does the job. 
So I was wondering, is there a way to call Yahoo contact importer through Yahoo api? (I've readed a thread on stackoverflow in which a user suggested this).

I've searched in Yahoo documentation, but did not find anything.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try [Facebook's Send Button](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/494/) if all you want to do is to let your users send invitations to their Facebook friends.

If you want to actually get their friends email addresses into your database, you'll need to teach them how to [import their Facebook friends into their Yahoo account](http://techcrunch.com/2010/03/04/yahoo-contacts-gets-facebook-connect/) first.

Once the addresses are in your users Yahoo account, you can integrate with the Yahoo API directly or use a [contact importer service](http://www.cloudsponge.com) like CloudSponge to do it for you.